# PHP array in alphabetic order in option drop down

Tags: php, arrays, json

the text below takes google sheet json output, turns it into php array and then filters just by football club. the outcome is a drop down list of football clubs, sorted in random order. i am having trouble sorting them by alphabetical order.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

//create array to store
$clubs=array(); 
//loop for each into array
foreach ($data['feed']['entry'] as $item) 
{
$clubs[]=  $item['gsx$clubs']['$t'];
}
//take array and get unique clubs
$clubs =array_unique($clubs);
//start select html


echo '<select>';
//print out unique clubs in option dropdown
foreach ($clubs as $key => $club) {
    echo '<option>' . $club . '</option>'  ;
}
//finish select html
echo '</select>';
```

when i print out print_r($clubs); it comes out like this

```
Array ( [0] => AFC Bournemouth [1] => Chelsea [2] => Wolverhampton Wanderers [3] => Crystal Palace [4] => Burnley [5] => Brighton & Hove Albion [6] => Tottenham Hotspur [8] => West Ham United [11] => Everton [12] => Manchester City [14] => Aston Villa [16] => Arsenal [20] => Manchester United [21] => Watford [23] => Sheffield United [28] => Southampton [30] => Newcastle United [39] => Norwich City [51] => Liverpool [71] => Leicester City )
```

so far i have already tried sort($clubs) and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Hi @miikegunn, where you put your `sort()` ?

Answer (score 0):

php code:

```
$asd = array(
    "AFC Bournemouth", 
    "Chelsea", 
    "Wolverhampton Wanderers", 
    "Crystal Palace", 
    "Burnley", 
    "Brighton & Hove Albion", 
    "Tottenham Hotspur"
    // ... 
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($asd);
echo "</pre>";

sort($asd);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($asd);
echo "</pre>";
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AFC Bournemouth
    [1] => Chelsea
    [2] => Wolverhampton Wanderers
    [3] => Crystal Palace
    [4] => Burnley
    [5] => Brighton & Hove Albion
    [6] => Tottenham Hotspur
)
Array
(
    [0] => AFC Bournemouth
    [1] => Brighton & Hove Albion
    [2] => Burnley
    [3] => Chelsea
    [4] => Crystal Palace
    [5] => Tottenham Hotspur
    [6] => Wolverhampton Wanderers
)
```

no problem, sorted alphabetically.

write what you want to receive in array?

Answer (score 0):

There are some sorting functions for PHP arrays already. I think sort() is what you want. Have to tried it? https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp
Usage:

```
<?php
$array = ["Newcastle United", "AFC Bournemouth", "Wolverhampton Wanderers", "Chelsea"];
sort($array);

print_r($array);
?>
```

Output

```
Array ( 
        [0] => AFC Bournemouth 
        [1] => Chelsea 
        [2] => Newcastle United 
        [3] => Wolverhampton Wanderers 
      )
```